# Beginner's confusion about this.close() function

Tags: c#

I was trying to use this.close() function to terminate a window, yes it works, however, Visual Studio did not stop the debugging, I need to manually press the stop button in VS, how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5792459/284240

Comment: Closing a window is not necessarily the same as exiting the application. There are a lot of programs that run without any windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program doesn't stop after new Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792010/program-doesnt-stop-after-new-window)

Comment: (Not *exactly* a duplicate but the accepted answer fits this question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your program you ll have something like that

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

You must close the Form passed as an argument in Application.Run in order to close your application. If we are speaking about Winforms.